# When will $C$ that minimizes $\lVert A-ZC\rVert$ be the same as one that minimizes $\lVert Z^{-1}A - C\rVert$ upto an orthogonal transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

When would be the solution $C$ that minimizes $\lVert A-ZC\rVert$ be the same as the one that minimizes $\lVert Z^{-1}A - C\rVert$ or say some scaled version $\alpha C$? All entries in square matrices $Z$, $A$ and $C$ are real.

Under what conditions is it invariant upto an orthogonal transformation say $P + qDC$ where $P$ is arbitrary matrix, $q$ is arbitrary nonzero number
and $D$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix.

I tried equating the two solutions to get the condition $$\left(Z^{2}\right)^{-1}Z^2 = \left(M^TM\right)^{-1}M^T$$ where $M = P + qDC $, if $Z$ is symmetric, and if not the condition is $\left(Z^TZ\right)^{-1}Z^T = \left(M^TM\right)^{-1}M^TZ^{-1}$. I ask this question to see if there is a better or broader take on this. In addition, would there be more to add if $C$ was always skew-symmetric and $Z$ was symmetric?

Comment: In which norm??

Comment: Either Frobenius norm or it's square

Comment: $A$ is a matrix. $Z c$ is a vector. You cannot subtract a vector from a matrix.

Comment: Ah silly mistake, my bad-added in a rush. I updated notation-made it capital and noted. Also added detail on invariance wrt orthogonal transformation.

Comment: I added what I tried, just now in an edit to the question.

Comment: What exactly is $M$?

Comment: $M$ is any $p+qDC$ where $p$ is arbitrary vector, $q$ is arbitrary nonzero number and $D$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix. This is already mentioned in question above

Comment: So, you are adding a vector to a matrix?

Comment: Ah. same typo, converted $p$ to capital letters. Am okay with assuming $P$ is a matrix of all zero's if required for simplicity -in saying something interesting. Also, each column of $P$ is identically the same.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If $Z$ is invertible, both norms are zero (and hence minimimised) at $C=Z^{-1}A$, aren't they?